# Can one configure Lead Conversion to transfer data into the Opportunity from the Lead, when the user chooses an existing opportunity in the wizard?

Tags: lead-conversion

If we could transfer the lead's ID into a field in the existing Opportunity, a trigger could later clear that field and perform the desired change, which is, append the lead source to a field that combines all the Lead Sources for the Opportunity.  (I assume that Lead Conversion cannot append to a field in the Wizard.)

Comment: No, you'd nee a trigger for this.

Comment: Thanks Fox. Could the trigger determine which Opportunity was the "existing" one during the Conversion ?